# Kotlin reference to Java Class<T> parameter

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I want to wrap a Java method in a Kotlin class, for convenience.

The Java method, from RxJava:

```
public <T> Observable<T> on(Class<T> p_class, Object p_context){
   return this.on(p_class, p_context, 0);
}
```

in Whatever.kt:

```
import com.dreamsocket.events.RxBus

val bus = RxBus()

fun on(c: ?????, o:Any): Observable<*****> {
    bus.on(c, o)
}
```

With what should I replace the `?????` and the `*****`?

Comment: What is the error/warning?

Comment: That depends on what I try, which was a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [`reified type parameters`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters)?

```
inline fun <reified T> on(o:Any) : Observable<T> {
    return bus.on(T::class.java, o)
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but I really don't need to access the type, just pass the `c` through to `on(c,o)`

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the relation between `c` and `o`?

Comment: `o` is just some object... when called it seems always to be `this`... which is just an object of some class which implements an unrelated interface. I think somebody is using reflection in RxJava to make use of `o`, I'm not sure. I guess they're unrelated.

Comment: There needs to be two parameters into my `on()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but it seems that a basic [generic function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions) is what you are looking for:

```
fun <T> on(c: Class<T>, o: Any): Observable<T> {
    return bus.on(c, o)
}
```

To get Java `Class<T>` you have to call `::class.java` on the wanted class name, e.g. using the above function:

```
val observable: Observable<String> = on(String::class.java, o)
```